# Create a storyboard in PhoneGap 1.7

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova, storyboard

I have a question about using Xcode storyboard in the PhoneGap 1.7 project. 
I have created an empty PG project, added a storyboard file to the project and dragged a View Controller onto the storyboard. But I do not find the wayto bind this controller to the variable created by PhoneGap framework:

```
CDVViewController* viewController;
```

How do I bind it if I can? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, as I said, I created a storyboard and put a ViewController on it. Then I tried to drag the created View Controller to the AppDelegate class (with ctrl pressed) as I would do to bind an outlet. This does not work... Google did not help. Can I use the storyboard with PhoneGap? BTW the idea behind it was to design the UI with storyboard and JS+PG for rest. I also found a nice plugin for PG called NativeControls which allows to create tab bars and other UI stuff directly in JS with some calls to native libraries but still would be nice to design UI with storyboard...

Comment: I understood the discription, but can you please paste the code here, not just one line. And what do you mean by `This does not work`? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you bind the ViewController in InterfaceBuilder to the *CDVViewController* class or your own subclass. It might also be useful to add a webview in the IB and bind it to the CDVCordovaView of the above view controller.

One thing you need to take care of is the fact that the *CDVViewController* does not implement the `initWithCoder:` method (as of Cordova 2.2.0), which is required for Storyboard usage. Add the following method to *CDVViewController*, so your view controller get's correctly initialized when instantiated from Storyboards:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self __init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This issues has now been fixed in Cordova 3.1 [CB-4539](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4539).